# Finding config file for foreign language toggle hotkey

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support, input-language

I have Korean and English as my input sources. The Korean language toggle key is set to shift + space, however that does nothing discernible. Opening ibus (ibus-setup) shows the next input method is space, however that also does nothing discernible.

Neither of keys changed the input language, however I randomly pressed super+alt+backspace, which changed the language.

Where can I find the source of this configuration? All the posts I've found here reference "Region and Language" and ibus-setup, but those don't do anything afaik.

Comment: Does anyone know?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: yes, ubuntu 20.03

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to toggle foreign language keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426552/how-to-toggle-foreign-language-keyboard)