# How to toggle foreign language keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus

I have Korean and English as my input sources. The Korean language toggle key is set to shift + space, however that does nothing discernible. Opening ibus (ibus-setup) shows the next input method is space, however that also does nothing discernible.

Neither of keys changed the input language, however I randomly pressed super+alt+backspace, which changed the language.

Where can I find the source of this configuration? All the posts I've found here reference "Region and Language" and ibus-setup, but those don't shortcuts don't toggle the language.

Comment: Are you using standard Ubuntu (with GNOME) or one of the Ubuntu flavors?

Comment: yes ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

The default shortcut to change keyboard layouts in Ubuntu desktop is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> will select the previous layout (if you have multiple). Please try these combinations. These shortcuts can be changed in "Settings" - "Keyboard", "Keyboard shortcuts", section "Typing".

Answer (score 0):

The confusion sometimes happen,
reach these settings, and if nothing changed after that, you might reconsider your desktop environment to be xfce4, to save your self the time to seek out, what's the main issue, if you'tr concerned about time. At xfce4 its shift+alt or super+alt when default.

[image]

In case you want to go to xfce4, then just install by `sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to alternate between Korean inputting and English typing.

Either you can **switch** between the *Korean (Hangul)* and *English (US)* input sources. As [vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium) mentioned, the default shortcut for doing so is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Or you can switch to *Korean (Hangul)* and only use that input source. The <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut then **toggles** between English mode and Hangul mode.